# Objective C : can't operate download issue

Tags: objective-c

i'm new to Xcode objective-c and I have a task to make a newsletter that downloadable.
So, I got some source code and tweak a bit but I got some error that said

"Implicit conversion loses integer precision : 'long' to 'int'

here are my code

```
-(void)downloadIssue:(IssueInfo*)issueInfo{

    NewsstandDownloader* downloader = [[AppDelegate instance] newsstandDownloader];
    downloader.delegate = self;

    long index = [self.publisher indexOfIssue:issueInfo];
    [downloader downloadIssue:issueInfo forIndexTag:index]; <-- Error
}
```

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a compiler *warning* and a mild one at that.  If you were dealing with a document that had more than, say, 32000 pages then you might need to be concerned about it.

The way to solve the problem is to either change the declaration of the function you're calling to something like:

```
[downloader downloadIssue:(IssueInfo *)issueInfo forIndexTag:(long)index]
```

or, simply use a cast:

```
int index = (int)[self.publisher indexOfIssue:issueInfo];
```

"`int`" isn't usually a good thing to use in Objective C as there are different lengths and capacities to it on different platforms (32 bit versus 64 bit, iOS vs MacOS, etc.).  It's better to use something more Objective-C specific, like NSInteger or NSUInteger.

Comment: tq very much sir, sorry for this small things question.
I'm really blind about Xcode.